# User of having multiple JREs in Control Panel Java Applet

Tags: java, applet, controls, panel

Can anyone explain the use of having multiple JRE's in the Control Panel Applet of Java? 
Refer to attached snapshot http://ge.tt/5YRkjNm/v/0?c of the location i am referring to.

Answer (score 2):

An applet or desktop app. deployed using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) can request a specific version of the JRE in the launch file.

Answer (score 0):

Different JREs have different compatibility issues. Code that worked on an earlier version of java may not work on a later version. Also, if there's multiple JREs, it may be hard to decide on one to keep. Thus, it's best to let the user choose.

Comment: My Question is, how can the application choose which jre it need to use or how can the user tell the application to use specific jre ?

Comment: There is no way for the app to chose its JRE except by spawning a second JVM for that JRE, which isn't elegant at all.

Comment: Then what is the use of adding different JRE's there?

Comment: So java can keep track of them all? I really don't know.

Comment: No. There is an option to add/remove multiple JRE's. As the option exists, i believe there should be some use of having it there.

Comment: *"There is no way for the app to chose its JRE except by spawning a second JVM for that JRE"*  Of course it can.  See my answer.